# select element with class and id with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select two different elements with class and id, the first works but the second doesn't (it works without the id), I can't figure out why.
help me, please.

**code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var num = 0;
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("main").append("<div class=\"card\" style=\"width: 20rem;\">\
    <div class=\"card-block\">\
    <h4 class=\"card-title\" id=\"" + num.toString() + "\"></h4>\
    <p class=\"card-text\" id=\"" + num.toString() + "\"></p>\
    </div>\
    </div>");
    var title = $("#noteTitle").val();
    var body = $("#noteBody").val();
    var photo = $("#notePhoto").val();
    if (photo) {
        $(".card").prepend("<img class=\"card-img-top\" src=" + photo + " alt=\"Card Image\">");
    }
    $(".card-title#"+ num.toString()).html(title);
    $(".card-text#"+ num.toString()).html(body); //<-- here is where I get the problem
    num ++;
});
})
```

Comment: Firstly, I'm guessing `$('main')` should be `$('#main')`. Secondly, please, please *please* do not use incremental `id` attributes. Your problem can be solved *so* much easier and cleaner by using common classes, delegated event handlers and DOM traversal. Lastly, use `'` to delimit the string so that you can then use `"` inside the string without all the ugly escape characters

Comment: To solve your actual problem, don't repeat the same `id` attribute in the DOM - they must be unique: https://jsfiddle.net/jp5yv03o/

Comment: Thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution . https://jsfiddle.net/0knefedh/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var num = 0;
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("body").append("<div class=\"card\" style=\"width: 20rem;\">\
    <div class=\"card-block\">\
    <h4 class=\"card-title\" id=\"title" + num.toString() + "\"></h4>\
    <p class=\"card-text\" id=\"text" + num.toString() + "\"></p>\
    </div>\
    </div>");
    var title = "dasdasd";
    var body = "asdasdas";
    var photo = $("#notePhoto").val();
    if (photo) {
        $(".card").prepend("<img class=\"card-img-top\" src=" + photo + " alt=\"Card Image\">");
    }
    $(".card-title#title"+ num.toString()).html(title);
    console.log(num);
    $(".card-text#text"+ num.toString()).html(body); //<-- here is where I get the problem
    num ++;
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="add" value="Add" >Add</button>
```

Problem is with **ID** that you are generating for **.card-title** and **.card-body**. Both are having same ID, where as **ID** should be unique.

So, it work for the first time then it didn't.

Comment: Our goal here is to educate people. 'Here you go' helps in the short term, but means people learn nothing. If you explain what the issue is and why your code helps, then you teach people for when they encounter the same issue in the future

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan... Just wait.... don't judge people so fast.. Check out my post. Don't just try to comment. I told you in my last comment as well.

Comment: We both know if I hadn't left that comment you wouldn't have edited that description. 10 seconds browsing through your answer history is enough evidence of that.

Comment: I was editing my post by that time you commented.... just wait some time before commenting.... Any way I appreciate your move, but it's not the place to discuss this.